# Create Multiple DataFrames using Rolling Window from DataFrame Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have one year's worth of data at four minute time series intervals. I need to always load 24 hours of data and run a function on this dataframe at intervals of eight hours. I need to repeat this process for all the data in the ranges of 2021's `start` and `end` dates.

**For example:**

Load `year_df` containing ranges between `2021-01-01 00:00:00` and `2021-01-01 23:56:00` and run a function on this.

Load `year_df` containing ranges between `2021-01-01 08:00:00` and `2021-01-02 07:56:00` and run a function on this.

Load `year_df` containing ranges between `2021-01-01 16:00:00` and `2021-01-02 15:56:00` and run a function on this.

```
#Proxy DataFrame
year_df = pd.DataFrame()
start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:00:00', infer_datetime_format=True)
end = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-31 23:56:00', infer_datetime_format=True)
myIndex = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='4T')
year_df = year_df.rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'delete'}).drop('delete', axis=1).reindex(myIndex).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Timestamp'})

year_df.head()
    Timestamp
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00
1   2021-01-01 00:04:00
2   2021-01-01 00:08:00
3   2021-01-01 00:12:00
4   2021-01-01 00:16:00
```

Comment: `rolling(..).apply` doesn't seem to be implemented yet, so an answer may depend on exactly what the function you're wanting to use is

Answer (score 0):

This approach avoids explicit for loops but the apply method is essentially a for loop under the hood so it's not that efficient.  But until more functionality based on rolling datetime windows is introduced to pandas then this might be the only option.

The example uses the mean of the timestamps.  Knowing exactly what function you want to apply may help with a better answer.

```
s = pd.Series(myIndex, index=myIndex)

def myfunc(e):
    temp = s[s.between(e, e+pd.Timedelta("24h"))]
    return temp.mean()

s.apply(myfunc)
```